# array split, into row and column 2-d Array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, jagged-arrays

i have tried to split a ByteArray (that represents a screenShot Data) into 
a 2d array so if i have for example an array of 3x3 (xy /rows columns)

it would look like this

```
int screenSwidth = 3;
int screenSheight = 3;
byte[] ScreenShot = new byte[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

i am trying via 2 nested for loops, to split the serial data into 
separated rows in a **new** 2dimentional array as it was shaped/formed originaly on the screen.

lets Just call the **new** ScreenShotRows[] as "b" just for this example

b[0][0] = **1** b[0][1] = **2** b[0][2] = **3**

b[1][0] = **4** b[1][1] = **5** b[1][2] = **6**

b[2][0] = **7** b[2][1] = **8** b[2][2] = **9**

and the question is **what is the right way to iterate through the whole array** 
i was trying to achieve that via this code .

```
     for (int HeightIter= 0; HeightIter < screenSheight; HeightIter++)
     {
           for (int WidthIter = 0; WidthIter < screenSwidth ; WidthIter++)
                {
                     ScreenShotRows[HeightIter, WidthIter] = ScreenShot[WidthIter];
                }
     }
```

and it loops over the first row , asigning the values :

b[0][0] = **1** b[0][1] = **2** b[0][2] = **3**

b[1][0] = **1** b[0][1] = **2** b[0][2] = **3**

b[2][0] = **1** b[0][1] = **2** b[0][2] = **3**

this is my first attempt on this kind of multiDimetional /jagged array 
with nested for loop,
and i found it very confiusing to make it work

also to get it done as fast as it could be,

cause my data is much larger than 3x3 , and method is called multiple times frequently so performance is crucial

my next move will be to have same way with the columns

elements 0,0 to 0,2 ---- elements 1,0 to 1,2 ---- ements 2,0 to 2,2

```
      147                    258                369
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your firsts line to:

```
for (int HeightIter= 0; HeightIter < screenSheight; HeightIter++)
```

And the line `ScreenShotRows[HeightIter, WidthIter] = ScreenShot[WidthIter];` to

```
ScreenShotRows[HeightIter, WidthIter] = ScreenShot[3*HeightIter+WidthIter];
```

This should make 2d array.

Comment: i've renamed it here so it's only a typo . i've fixed it now , that's not what is wrong though

Comment: Just checked my code with debugger - it works. How do you know how your 2D array looks like? Via debugger?

Comment: Rather than hard coding the `3`, you should probably use `screenSwidth`.  Magic numbers are bad.

Comment: yea , only that way i learn , i've checked it with microscope(debugger) and for the 3 , i was wondering which parameter to use while i was reading then refreshed the page and u made your comment on this , i'll give it a try , Thanks a lot Seeker +Servy

Comment: @servy indeed. Thanks for critic.

Comment: sure i havent had the time to correct it in VS by now but it will take only one sec... it does look as the right one , made it as aceepted.thanks again